# Montar Array para API

Tags: php, api

Bom dia a todos.
Acredito que minha pergunta seja primária mas estou apanhando muito.
Aqui na empresa vamos utilizar um ERP on-line no qual pretendemos incluir os nossos pedidos de venda (utilizando PHP) via APIs desse ERP. Uma das partes da API de inclusão de pedidos trata das parcelas de pagamento e, segundo os exemplos deles, a estrutura para interação é a seguinte:

```
"lista_parcelas": {
"parcela": [
  {
    "data_vencimento": "02/10/2019",
    "numero_parcela": 1,
    "percentual": 50,
    "valor": 100
  },
  {
    "data_vencimento": "28/03/2020",
    "numero_parcela": 2,
    "percentual": 50,
    "valor": 100
  }
]
```

},

Eu tentei montar o array assim:

```html
$chave->lista_parcelas = array("parcela" => array("data_vencimento" => "31/10/2019",
      "numero_parcela" => 1,
      "percentual" => 40,
      "valor" => 120),
    "parcela" => array("data_vencimento" => "05/11/2019",
      "numero_parcela" => 2,
      "percentual" => 60,
      "valor" => 180));
```

Mas quando verifiquei o resultado, apenas a 2ª parcela foi gravada.

Então, tentei assim:

```html
$chave->lista_parcelas = array("parcela" => array("data_vencimento" => "31/10/2019",
      "numero_parcela" => 1,
      "percentual" => 40,
      "valor" => 120),
    array("data_vencimento" => "05/11/2019",
      "numero_parcela" => 2,
      "percentual" => 60,
      "valor" => 180));
```

Assim, dá erro dizendo que alguma informação não faz parte da estrutura.

Acredito que seja erro meu de programação. Alguém poderia me dar uma luz de como construir corretamente esse exemplo ?
Agradeço desde já.

Answer (score -1):

```
$a = array(

    "parcela" => array(

        array("data_vencimento" => "31/10/2019",
            "numero_parcela" => 1,
            "percentual" => 40,
            "valor" => 120),

        array("data_vencimento" => "05/11/2019",
            "numero_parcela" => 2,
            "percentual" => 60,
            "valor" => 180)

    )


);

$chave->lista_parcelas = json_encode($a);
```

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta mas, apesar de criar o pedido, a rotina dá o seguinte erro:
Warning: Creating default object from empty value in ..... na linha do $a = array...

Comment: Já consegui resolver. Obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: @cfreitasc como resolveste?

Comment: tirei o json_encode. Minha rotina faz esse método mais adiante.